# Why do attempts to update a user's password in this Codeigniter 3 application fail?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **[blog application](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog/tree/password_reset_system)** in **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4.

I have added a **registration and login** system to this application. I am current working on a password reset system.

I can't figure out why updating a user's password fails as below:

[image]

In the **Newpassword** controller I have:

```
class Newpassword extends CI_Controller {
    private $token = NULL;

    public function index($token = NULL) {
        //echo $token; die();
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['tagline'] = 'New password';
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $this->token = $token;
    
         // Form validation rules
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
         $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
    
        if(!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('auth/newpassword');
            $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        } else {
            $this->add();
        }
    }

    public function add() {
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['tagline'] = 'New password';
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    
        // Encrypt new password
        $enc_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
        // Update password column
        $token = $this->token;
    
        if ($this->Usermodel->set_new_password($token, $enc_password)) {
            redirect('login'); 
            $this->session->set_flashdata("new_password_success", "Your new password was set. You can login");
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("new_password_fail", "We have failed updating your password");
            redirect('/newpassword'); 
        }
      }
    }
```

In the **Usermodel** model I have:

```
public function set_new_password($token, $enc_password) {
    $this->db
        ->where(['token' => $token])
        // set new password and reset token to NULL
        ->update('authors', array('password' => $enc_password, 'token' => NULL));
}
```

The form:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('newpassword/add')); ?>
  <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('password')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <?php if(form_error('password')) echo form_error('password'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('cpassword')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <?php if(form_error('cpassword')) echo form_error('cpassword'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="submit" value="Set password" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
  </div>            
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

If I uncomment `//echo $token; die();` from the controller, the token is printed with the expected value. Yet, the password does not update (and the failure to update it is correctly displayed).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `->where(['token' => $token])` to `->where('token', $token)`. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: @AdamP. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click **Set password** button redirected to `newpassword/add` but the **token** not exists here, because used it only a previous step:

1. Password reset request
2. Click link in email (token exist)
3. Fill the form and click "Set password" (send form data to **newpassword/add**) - the token is not exist here but you want to use it: `$token = $this->token;` but now the "token" is: **add**

<s>Sorry, you must be refactoring your password reset code logic. I think this is harder to fix than rewriting the whole process</s>

**UPDATE:**

Add `$data['token'] = $token;` into **index** method in **Newpassword controller**

AND

***modify form action url*** in `views/auth/newpassword.php` to this:
`<?php echo form_open(base_url('newpassword/add/'.$token)); ?>`

**IMPORTANT!!!**

Add **return** to ell functions in model:
`return $this->db-> ....`
And put `redirect('<url>')` **after** set session flashdata!

I tested it and I think fixed the problem.

Comment: Then there is something different in your code that is not up in the github repo. I pulled it down from there 1.5 hours ago and only modified the ones posted here

Comment: You can see how it came out in the end **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511552/4512005)**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final, working code for the password update (in case anybody else needs it):

In the **Newpassword** controller:

```
class Newpassword extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($token = NULL)
    {
        $data               = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages']      = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['tagline']    = 'New password';
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $data['token']      = $token;
        
        // Form validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
        
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('auth/newpassword');
            $this->load->view('partials/footer');
        } else {
            // Encrypt new password
            $enc_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            
            if ($this->Usermodel->set_new_password($token, $enc_password)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("new_password_success", "Your new password was set. You can login");
                redirect('login');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("new_password_fail", "We have failed updating your password");
                redirect('/newpassword/' . $token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the model:

```
public function set_new_password($token, $enc_password) {
    return $this->db
        ->where('token', $token)
        // set new password and reset token to NULL
        ->update('authors', array('password' => $enc_password, 'token' => NULL));
}
```

The form (view):

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('newpassword/'. $token)); ?>
  <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('password')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <?php if(form_error('password')) echo form_error('password'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('cpassword')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <?php if(form_error('cpassword')) echo form_error('cpassword'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="submit" value="Set password" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
  </div>            
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```